# How to Redirect 1 url to another when you click on anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I need a single code for that when I click on anchor tag, it redirects to a URL and after some time it redirects to an another url.

Kind of double url redirection on single code.

I tried to manipulate this code for double url redirection.

Comment: Hello please read first how to ask it's not easy to understand what you want https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of  double url redirection

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('https://www.w3schools.com/html/');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want to navigate or add some time then create a function in  and  apply timeout method for second navigation

// Case 2 In order to open the second url after some time

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>


        <a href="#" onclick=myFunction()>Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>

        <script>

        function myFunction(){
           myWindow = window.open('http://google.com');
if(myWindow){ // if its null means the 1 one is not opened hence second //will not open
            setTimeout(function(){ 
             window.open('https://www.w3schools.com/html/');
             }, 1000); 
}       
            }
       </script>
        </body> 
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working.. but I want to redirect both link in one new single tab. And the 2nd link should open after few seconds. Can you help me.

Comment: @Nick as i mentioned you need to add timeOut function. so edited the post

Comment: Hi, the second link is opening as popup... Like mine many people block popups in their system or phones. So is that possible to open 2nd link without popup.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in which language you'd want your solution. along the chain of PHP-html-javascript, there are 3 ways to go (which can be combined). Each with its own pros and cons
The simplest html way is using meta tag, where the content attribute hold the time to redirect (in seeconds) and the destination:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='https://destination.com/index.html'" />
```

The 2nd way, is using php redirect

```
header('Location: https://destination.com/index.html');
```

The 3rd way is with Javascript

```
window.location.href = "https://destination.com/index.html";
```

A quick example (combing all three, to be played with)
a small remark, for an html only solution, 2 files will be needed for 2 redirects. JS and PHP can allow you use the same file, by adding a counter to the url and reading from it (with an addition of ?counter=x)

```
<?php
$counter = isset($_GET['counter']) ? 1 : $_GET['counter'] +1;
$redit = "1.html";
if ($counter == 2) $redir = "3.html";
header('Location: https://destination.com/' . $redir .  '?counter=' . $counter);
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='https://destination.com/index.html'" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="2.html">click me</a>
<script type="text/Javascript">
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var counter = urlParams.get('counter');
        var redir = "2.html";
        counter++;
        if (counter == 2) {
                redir = "3.html";
        }
        window.location.href = "https://destination.com/" + redir + counter;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On first page:

```
<a href="second_page.php?redirect=true>Link</a>
```

On second page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['redirect']) && $_GET['redirect'] == true){
        sleep(2);
        header("Location: http://example.com/third_page.php"); 
    }
```